# Bug in gcloud -- BQ component 2.0.95

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gcloud

On │ BigQuery Command Line Tool      │     2.0.95 │  1.6 MiB │

GCLOUD version: version: 441.0.0

version , when tried to update a bigquery connection with the following flags:

```html
bq update --connection --connection_type=CLOUD_SQL '--properties={"instanceId" : "XXXXXXX:us-east1:XXXXXX","database" : "XXXXXXX", "type" : "MYSQL" }' '--connection_credential={"username":"readonlyuser", "password":"XXXXXXXXXX"}' XXXXXXXX.us.XXXXXX
```

It is failing with error :
UpdateConnection() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_kms_key'

I didn't provided the default_kms_key flag in my cmd still its populating and failing with same error .

I reverted to previous version that i was working with : {version is: 438.0.0.} i got no error and update went fine . Can some one let me know if anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: To report a bug, create a bug report at Google's Issue Tracker. Here is a [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). That group tends to be very fast responding and allocating engineering resources.

Comment: Thanks Jhon , seems google is already aware of the issue and they are working on the fix .

Comment: Can you update your question with the Issue Tracker URL? Once there is a resolution, post an answer.

Comment: This should be fixed with SDK version 442.